# AWK with two file inputs - output depends on congruence between both input files

Tags: bash, awk

This is a long explanation, but I think the problem will be simple for you all. Here goes:

I have two input files. One of them looks something like this:

```
data.frq
     CHR  SNP   A1   A2          MAF  NCHROBS
       2  fa0    T    C       0.2067      300
```

This file exists in 1000 folders (`/home/user/data/run1/data.frq` through `/home/user/data/run1000/data.frq`) for repeated #'s of runs, and is specific to that run.

The other:

```
1 G
2 G
3 T
4 G
5 T
6 G
7 T
8 G
9 T
10 T
11 T
12 C
13 A
14 G
15 G
...
1000 C
```

What I need to do is look at every `data.frq` file (the first input file above) and report the `MAF` (which is in column 5, value 0.2067). So far I am able to do this with this AWK script:

```
awk 'FNR == 2 {print FILENAME, $5}' data/run*/data.frq | sort -V
```

Which outputs the following:

```
run-1/data/data.frq 0.91333
run-2/data/data.frq 0.94667
run-3/data/data.frq 0.93333
run-4/data/data.frq 0.8867
run-5/data/data.frq 0.88
run-6/data/data.frq 0.8267
run-7/data/data.frq 0.8533
run-8/data/data.frq 0.7133
run-9/data/data.frq 0.9
run-10/data/data.frq 0.8333
run-11/data/data.frq 0.7867
run-12/data/data.frq 0.86
run-13/data/data.frq 0.92667
run-14/data/data.frq 0.8867
run-15/data/data.frq 0.94
down to run-1000
```

This output is great so far, but what I don't know how to do is take the 2nd input file above and compare it to the first. If the second column of input 2 (In this case it's G for run-1) is different from the 3rd column of input 1, I need 1-MAF (1-$5). If they are the same, I need MAF ($5). So basically, I need to know how to put this if statement into my awk script:

```
if $2 of file2 == $3 of file1, print $5 of file1
else print (1-$5) of file1
```

So for the above example, it would print 0.7933 (which is 1-MAF since G!=T)

Hopefully that makes some sense to someone!

Comment: Is it wishful thinking, or is there a vast untapped market for awk coders in the genomics space? ; -) .... I think you'll have to have one of the files stored in an array or merge files before using awk, as there is no way (that I'm aware of) to do `if $2 of file2 == $3 of file1, print $5 of file1`. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter: Interesting marketing suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the first column of "file2" (which you don't otherwise name) contains the run number so that you can compute the name of the corresponding `data.frq` file using string concatenation:

```
frq = "run-" $1 "/data/data.frq"
```

(Here I'm using the sample output rather than the problem description. Precision is always useful :) )

That basically allows for a fairly simple `awk` program. Here's one possibility, with lots of comments.

```
awk '{
        # construct the filename for the data file
        frq = "run-" $1 "/data/data.frq"
        # read (and ignore) the first line
        getline tmp<frq
        # read the second line
        getline tmp<frq;
        # and split it into fields
        split(tmp, field)
        # Now do the computation
        if ($2 == field[3]) print frq, field[5]
        else print frq, 1 - field[5]
        # Close the input file so we don't run out of fd's
        close(frq)
     }' file2
```

Comment: Thank you! I got this running pretty well. One additional thing I might request is kind of a QC measure. Could you get it to output $3 from file1 and $2 file file2 in two additional columns? That way we can see if they are the same or not, and if they are, the value should be less than 0.5 if everything is working properly. Thanks again, this was super helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this (formatting inserted for clarity):

```
 awk 'NR == FNR { v[$1] = $2 }
      NR != FNR { if ( $2 != v[$1] )
                    $3 = 1.0 - $3;
                  print $1, $3
                }' file2.txt <(
      awk 'NF == 6 && $1 != "CHR" { f=gensub("[^[:digit:]]","","g",FILENAME);
                                    print f, $3, $5
                                  }' run-*/data/data.frq
                              )
```

This runs two `awk` processes. The inner one, inside the `<( ... )` process substitution block, reads all your `data.frq` files, strips out the number from the `FILENAME`, rather than just using the whole thing, then prints the test number, the A1 and the MAF values from each file, by finding the line that has 6 fields, but where the fields are not the headers.

The outer `awk` command first reads your `file2.txt` and stores away the number and value for each in the `v[]` array, then reads the output of the inner `awk`, and if the stored value for that test number and the value from the A1 field in the `data.frq` file do not match, it adjusts the MAF value, and then prints the test number and (possibly adjusted) MAF value for each line.

Edit: The outer `awk` distinguishes between the input from `file2.txt` and the process substitution output by comparing two internal `awk` variables - NR, which is the current overall record (line) number being processed across all input files, and FNR, which is the record number within the current file. For the first file processed, you will have `FNR == NR` - this leads to a common idiom in `awk` for pre-loading some data from a first file before processing data in subsequent files.

Comment: +1 Looks good. Maybe it's worth making it clear that the `NR==FNR` means the first block operates on the first file (and why). Also, you could use `next` in the first block rather than having a condition on the second.

Comment: @TomFenech I'll add in a bit about NR/FNR. And the point about `next` is valid, but I'm not entirely sure it really gains anything in efficiency - it could also all be done entirely in one unconditional block with an extra `if`. There's generally more than one way to skin a `cat`...

Comment: No pun intended I'm sure. I wasn't meaning from an efficiency point of view, it just looks odd to me checking for two mutually exclusive conditions like that. Entirely a matter of taste, I agree.